# sh script works manually but not via cron

Tags: shell, server, cron, ubuntu-16.04, nextcloud

I'm trying to run a sh script from crontab. If I run script manually it works perfect, but when I run it in crontab, I get errors.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo tar -zcvf /var/www/nextcloud/data/nextcloud/files/backup.tar.gz /home/beno/stuff/
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/nextcloud/occ file:scan --all >> /var/www/nextcloud/data/nextcloud/files/backup_log.txt
```

The script is supposed to make a tar backup of a folder and put it in nextcloud folder and run command files:scan, so nextcloud rescans filesystem and starts synchronization...as I read it here:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html#file-operations-label

When crontab runs the script, backup.tar.gz is created, then I get following error:

```
An unhandled exception has been thrown: 
Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/DB/Connection.php:60
```

I'm using ubuntu16 and nextcloud11. Please help!

Comment: Did you mean **bash** script, rather than **sh** script?  Your description and code are not consistent in that respect.

Comment: To emphasize what Toby said -- something is a **bash** script if it's interpreted by `/bin/bash`, which your shebang is requesting. Bash scripts have a wider set of features available than POSIX sh scripts, which use a `#!/bin/sh` shebang and are only guaranteed to have language features defined in the POSIX sh standard supported by their interpreter.